# Python- How to execute shell cmd 'last | grep "logged in"' use subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, shell

I want to execute this shell command in Python and get return result, but the following codes could't get the correct result.

```
command = 'last | grep "logged in"'
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sto, err = p.communicate()
```

the right result should like this

`root     pts/0        218.17.185.24    Tue Dec 10 15:34   still logged in`

but what i got is this

`wtmp begins Wed Nov 27 18:30:26 2019`

Who has ideas for this question? Thanks for first!!!

Comment: One solution would be to just do `last` and filter the `logged in` part in Python... But I've played a bit with the `Popen` and couldn't make it work with grep. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using `os.system` instead?

```
import os
os.system('last | grep "logged in"')
```

Gives me the following:

```
user    pts/0        1.2.3.4      Tue Dec 10 11:13   still logged in
```

EDIT: To store the output:

```
import os
result = os.popen('last | grep "logged in"').read()
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can store the output into a variable?